# need help finding comprehensive netbeans plugin development tutorials

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to develop/create a plugin, but I can't seem to find a [good] series of tutorials covering the broad range of topics that are involved in doing so. I have already found the [Developer FAQ Page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ), the [NetBeans Platform Learning Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html), and the [NetBeans Platform 7.3 Plugin Quick Start](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html), but none of those, or similar sites on netbeans.org have a[n extensive] tutorial on plugin development. So my question basically is: does anyone know a good, comprehensive tutorial for developing netbeans plugins. As always, any information, resources, or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference.  A NetBeans plugin is a bunch of code that alters the behavior of NetBeans itself, usually to add features.  A module is a bunch of code developed using NetBeans for some other purpose.  A module could also implement a plugin for another system.  Describe what the thing is for and it will be clearer how to answer.

Comment: @MelNicholson Based on your definition, I am trying to create a plugin. What it does is it enables the user to choose from various Look and Feels and then automatically applies it to the current project (given that it is a GUI-based application).

Comment: Just in case, be sure to check http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/ for someone who has already done this before you write your own.

Comment: @MelNicholson I can't seem to find anyone else who has done something similar, which is all the more reason to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the documentation you could possible want:

http://netbeans.org/kb/index.html

Tutorials:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html

Plug-Ins:

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, my only problem is that I have no idea where to go from there. Any clarification would be great :)

Comment: Looking at the second source, I can't find anything about plugins and their development. I appreciate the followup, but sources that pertain to my topic would be best.

Comment: I edited my post, hope that tutorial plugin helps you! Youtube is also a great resource for this kind of stuff. Any particular question you had?

Comment: My only problem is trying to find something past the "Quick Start" guide. I have seen the 3rd page you post already, and my only problem with it is that it doesn't give a very good pathway into the rest of the process.

Comment: The first link is not a documentation page, but more of a collection of official Netbeans "Learning Trails", the second source doesn't seem to have any relevance to plugin development, and the third is just the Netbeans Quick Start, that hardly provides an adequate source.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you still looking for an answer, that's the [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html) you're looking for I presume. the video in this link is quite descriptive of how to look around in the doc and is a very good quick start guide you have also applications tutorial that are real-world examples built step by step, there is even a book: Netbeans Platform for beginners if you want to go deeper, a list of videos are available [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-10-top-apis.html) ... basically just look carefully in the first link it has many resources they're just scattered.